# What is the Fastest way to compare values across columns in pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, np.nan, 1], [1, np.nan, 1, 1]]),
                    columns=['t', 't_1', 't_2', 't_3'])
```

Which in reality have ~10 Million rows.
I need a fast way to know which is the last consecutive column that have a non null value.
Taking this df as an example the results would be ->

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, np.nan, np.nan], [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]),
                    columns=['t', 't_1', 't_2', 't_3'])
```

currently I'm doing this with the following lambda function, but the result is too slow:

```
def second_to_last_null(*args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
        if np.isnan(args[i]):
            return np.nan
        else:
            return args[-1]


df_result['t'] = df['t']
df_result['t_1_consecutive'] = df[['t', 't_1']].apply(lambda x: second_to_last_null(x.t, x.t_1), axis=1)
df_result['t_2_consecutive'] = df[['t', 't_1', 't_2']].apply(lambda x: second_to_last_null(x.t, x.t_1, x.t_2), axis=1)
df_result['t_3_consecutive'] = df[['t', 't_1', 't_2', 't_3']].apply(lambda x: second_to_last_null(x.t, x.t_1, x.t_2, x.t_3), axis=1)
```

Can somebody suggest the fastest way to do this in Pandas or Numpy?
A simple technical explanation as to why that method is better than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cumsum` on `isna`, then `mask`

```
df_result = df.mask(df.isna().cumsum(axis=1) >= 1)
```

Output:

```
     t  t_1  t_2  t_3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Explanation**: `df.isna()` mask the `nan` with `True`, else `False`. Then taking the `cumsum(axis=1)` allow you to find the cumulative number of `nan` so far (on the rows). Finally, all `cumsum` >= 1 indicates that there is a `nan` before that position.

Comment: kudos to you for understanding that function so quickly!

Comment: @QuangHoang I guess we can also use `cummax` to simplify things: `df[~df.isna().cummax(1)]`  :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you, that was a very nice response! I still don't understand why my method was soo slow (around 20 mins) and yours is almost instant (3s)

Comment: @ClaudioMarianoHurtadoSepulv `lambda` is essentially a `for` loop, which is Python native and is slow. My solution utilizes vectorized C methods.

Comment: Long live to the C vectorized methods then!